# Abel and Galois (and Arnold)

Tags: gr.group-theory, cv.complex-variables, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

**Question** Is there a connection between Abel and Galois theories of polynomial equations?

Recall that for every polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ (say, without the free coefficient), Abel considered the monodromy group of the Riemann surface of the analytic function $w(z)$ defined by  $p(w(z))+z=0$.. There is an expression of $w(z)$ in radicals if the monodromy group is solvable (is it an "if and only if" statement?).

On the other hand, for every polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, Galois considered the automorphism group (the Galois group) of the splitting field of $p$. The roots of $p(x)$ are expressed in radicals if and only if the Galois group is solvable.

The question asks whether there are any known connections between the monodromy group of $w(z)$ and the Galois group of $p(x)+z$ (considered as polynomial in $x$).

I am pretty sure this is well known. I just cannot find it in the literature.

**Update 1.** What I called "Abel's proof" of Abels' theorem is in fact Arnold's proof written by Alexeev (an English translation can be found [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/abel.pdf)). Abel's proof was based on different ideas, see [this text](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~jimlb/abel.pdf). So some instances of the word "Abel" above should be replaced by "Arnold". Added "Arnold" to the title.

**Update 2.** I found a very nice book by Askold Khovanskii, 
"[Topological Galois Theory](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642388705)", where Arnold's proof and its strong generalizations to other types of equations, including differential equations, are explained in detail. Highly recommended.

Comment: Does this mean that Abel discovered the concept of Riemann surfaces before Riemann ? Cause Abel died in 1829, when Riemann was only 3 years old.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN It is more of a surprise that Fermat had a proof of his theorem maybe around 1670, when Wiles had approximately  $-283$ years of age.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN As I recall, according to Pesic's book to "Abel's proof", one of the things which made Abel hard to read was that he worked with the language of multivalued analytic functions, which was later cleaned up by introducing the language of Riemann surfaces.  Abel certainly understood that $\sqrt{z}$ is $2$-fold branched at $0$, but (as I understand it) he wouldn't have thought of that as a map from some other surface to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: More amazingly, Galois discovered his theory about 60 years before abstract groups were defined. Most people explaining Galois theory now follow Artin's proof.

Comment: I sometimes think Galois would have been able to prove RH had he lived long enough. The fact that a teenager could do what he did is somewhat scary.

Comment: I'm not sure that we can localize so precisely the birth of abstract groups... what precisely are you referring to 60 years after Galois?

Comment: I mean the definition of a group as a set with a binary operation. I think  von Dyke was the first who defined it this way (in about 1882) and Galois died in 1832. So it should be 50 years instead of 60. On the other hand one can argue that the first systematic study of (abstract) groups was in the book by Burnside in 1902, 70 years after Galois death.

Comment: In this spirit, you might be interested in the monodromic proof of the impossibility of trisection, written by Terry Tao here:  https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/a-geometric-proof-of-the-impossibility-of-angle-trisection-by-straightedge-and-compass/

Comment: @Marty: It is interesting. Of course impossibility of trisection does not need any Galois theory. It immediately follows from the fact that if we have a chain of three fields $K_1<K_2<K_3$ then $|K_3:K_1|=|K_3:K_2||K_2:K_1|$ which has a very short proof (a few lines).   So using monodromy is an overkill.

Comment: I was under the impression that the abstract notion of group goes back at least as far as Cayley's 1854 paper (where he shows that every group is a subgroup of a permutation group, what we call Cayley's theorem). Cayley's paper may be found here: https://books.google.com/books?id=_LYConosISUC&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @ToddTrimble: The paper of Cayley does not have a definition of a group. The phrase on page 41 defines groupoids (magmas). But since he assumes that the elements denoted by the symbols are invertible functions and the operation is composition, one gets a group. Thus his groups consist of functions. He did define the Cayley (multiplication) table, and did notice the Cayley theorem.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: Indeed, Abel did not use Riemann surfaces. See the update in my question. For some reason I thought that Arnold's proof was a modification of Abel's but it is not correct.

Comment: Fix a branch of $w(z)$ analytic at $z_0$, let $w_\gamma(z)$ be all the functions analytic at $z_0$ that are an analytic continuation of $w(z)$ along some closed curve $\gamma$, now continuing those along any closed curve permutes the $w_\gamma(z)$ : this is the monodromy group $M(w)$. The coefficients of $f=\prod_{w_\gamma} (X-w_\gamma(z))$ stay the same under analytic continuation, thus together with the $O(|z-a|^{-k})$ growth at the isolated singularities it means they are meromorphic on the Riemann sphere ie. $f \in\Bbb{C}(z)[X]$ and $M(w) =Gal(\Bbb{C}(z,\bigcup w_\gamma)/\Bbb{C}(z))$.

Comment: Why did you edit to add a typo?

Comment: There was no dot at the end of a sentence and no space before the next sentence. I fixed that. Now for some reason there are two dots.I think that still it is better than none. It is what editing on the phone does.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The action of the monodromy group of $w(z)$ on the fiber $p^{-1}(a)$ for a non-critical value $a$ of $p$ (that is $|p^{-1}(a)|=\deg p$) is the same as the action of the Galois group of $p(x)+z$ over $\mathbb C(z)$ on the roots of $p(x)+z$ in some splitting field. One can see this by comparing each of these groups with the deck transformation group of the cover $X\to\mathbb P^1\mathbb C$, where $X$ is the normal hull of the cover $P^1\mathbb C\to P^1\mathbb C$, $x\mapsto p(x)$. (Remark: Though it doesn't make a difference, it is slightly more convenient to work with $p(x)-z$ instead of $p(x)+z$.)

Comment: So the monodromy group of $w(z)$ and the Galois group of $p(x)-z$ over $\mathbb{C}(z)$ are isomorphic? Can you give a reference to it?

Comment: @MarkSapir: It seems to me that Section I of a paper by Joe Harris ( http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077313717) covers that. Also, one finds the ingredients in Forster's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*, one essential piece being Theorem 8.12.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this was explored at length in the work Joseph Fels Ritt in the 1920s-1930s, who wrote it all up rather well, but it also appears in various Serre books (Topics in Galois Theory, I am pretty sure).

I am sure it appears in Serre's books, and certainly Topics in Galois Theory talks a lot of the function field case. As for Ritt, here is a random example (he wrote a lot on this in the twenties, most quite relevant):

*Ritt, J. F.*, [**On algebraic functions which can be expressed in terms of radicals.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1989045), American M. S. Trans. 24, 21-30 (1923). [ZBL49.0717.01](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:49.0717.01).

Another good source from all this is Jean-Pierre Tignol's book:

*Tignol, Jean-Pierre*, Galois’ theory of algebraic equations, Singapore: World Scientific. xiii, 333 p. (2001). [ZBL0972.12001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0972.12001).

Comment: Are you sure about Serre's book? Could you provide a reference to Ritt's work?

Comment: Ritt's paper does not contain the word "Galois". Do you know an answer to my question?

Comment: And Tígnol's book does not contain the word "monodromy".